# What's a decent jQuery print Area plugin?

Tags: jquery, printing

I tried finding a maintained or tested plugin for jquery that allows me to print a selected element from a page but all I found where some old or untested pieces of code.

Has anyone used a proper plugin for this yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please include what code / which plugins you already tried. How should we else know which links not to post just to hear from you "thanks already tried this..."

I suggest [jqPrint](https://github.com/tanathos/jquery.jqprint/)

Comment: +1 for jqprint.  Looks like that is the "accepted" way to print a selected element.

Comment: Works great for me in IE and FF but I'm having trouble getting it to work in Chrome.

Comment: Not available for download. Any new plug-ins yet?

Comment: Updated the link to the new home of jqPrint

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link for print functionality very easy and best

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

just pass your div id to print function to print data